# Google Translator for learning to pronounce correctly

Tags: webapp-rec

I am trying to figure out a good way for a non native English speaker to become proficient in pronunciations.

[Google Translator on Chrome](http://translate.google.com/) seems like a good option. It lets a person read out and it would process the speech and add text to the textbox.

I was looking for a logical extension to it. Is there an app which presents a text to read. As long as you read and pronounce correctly, it'll keep updating the completed status and wait on a particular word if you don't pronounce it correctly?

If this place is not the right place to ask this question, I apologize.

Comment: Hi, questions seeking application recommendations are considered off-topic for this site. See the [help/on-topic]. It might be on-topic for [softwarerecs.se], but your question needs to meet [certain guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information). Please read the guidelines and improve your question if needed, then you can repost your question on the [Software Recommendations site](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an app sort of like this?

**Sounds: The Pronunciation App**
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sounds-pronunciation-app-free/id428243918?mt=8

Answer (score -1):

[Duolingo](http://duolingo.com), though not exclusively focused on pronounciation, dedicate a part of each lesson to pronounce short phrases after hearing them, and validate the step only if pronounced correctly.

Answer (score -1):

[Auralog's Tell Me More](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auralog) is great for learning to pronounce correctly: after pronouncing a word or sentence it compares the soundwave with a perfect pronunciation, gives a score based on it and allows you to play back your pronounced words so that you can hear the difference. It supports many languages, including US and UK English.

[image]

Personally I use the voice recognition software Dragon NaturallySpeaking, which forces me to train everyday ;-)